# Weird log sequence proof.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let λ be a real number with 0 ≤ λ < 1, and let $(s_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be the sequence whose terms
are $s_n = 1 + λ + λ^2 + · · · + λ^n$
.

Prove that $(s_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} $converges as $n → ∞$, and find the
limit.

Your proof should use the $\epsilon-N$ definition of convergence.

My attempt is as follows:

$s_n = 1 + λ + λ^2 + · · · + λ^n= \frac{1- \lambda ^{n+1} }{1-\lambda}$
now as $n \to \infty $ $\lambda^{n+1} \to 0$ appears to go to zero.

Assume $s= \frac{1 }{1-\lambda}$ Attempt to prove:

SW: choose $\epsilon > 0 $
 WTS $\exists N$ s.t $ \forall n>N $ implies that $ |s_n - s | < \epsilon $

$|\frac{1- \lambda ^{n+1} }{1-\lambda} - \frac{1}{1-\lambda} |=|\frac{- \lambda ^{n+1} }{1-\lambda}| \leq \frac{ \lambda ^{n+1} }{1-\lambda}$ i am unsure of the last step here being a proper way to proceed as it's always negative?

$\frac{ \lambda ^{n+1} }{1-\lambda}<\epsilon \implies \lambda ^{n+1} < (1-\lambda)\epsilon$ Now here i want to restrict $\epsilon \leq 1 $ so that both sides of the expression are strictly less than 1 but i am not sure i can do that? as i am supposed to prove for all epsilon not all epsilon less than or equal to 1?

$-(n+1) < \log_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}[(1-\lambda)\epsilon]$ In this line i take $\log_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}$ as this makes it act like a regular log as $\frac{1}{\lambda}>1 $ since both sides are less than one does it flip signs twice?

i multiply both sides of the equation by negative one and get $(n+1) > -\log_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}[(1-\lambda)\epsilon]$

$n > -1-\log_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}[(1-\lambda)\epsilon]$

F.P let $N=\max \{ 1, -1-\log_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}[(1-\lambda)\epsilon]\}$ ( i just wanna make sure what i am writing makes sense.

choose any $ \epsilon $ s.t $ 1 \geq\epsilon >0 $ then $ \forall n > N $ we have $n>-1-\log_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}[(1-\lambda)\epsilon] \implies n+1>-\log_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}[(1-\lambda)\epsilon] \implies -(n+1)<\log_{\frac{1}{\lambda}}[(1-\lambda)\epsilon]  \implies \lambda^{-(-(n+1))} <(1-\lambda)\epsilon   $ which implies that $\frac { \lambda^{(n+1)} }{(1-\lambda)} <\epsilon   $

Since $ |s_n - s | \leq\frac { \lambda^{(n+1)} }{(1-\lambda)} < \epsilon $

hence $(s_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} $ converges to $s= \frac{1 }{1-\lambda} $

I am confused about restricting my epsilon to being less than or equal to 1 and confused by the weird log cause both values are negative so isn't it like i'm multiplying by negative one when i take that log?

Comment: You don't have to concern yourself with restricting epsilon to only smaller ones. If you look carefully, if some $N$ works for small enough epsilon ($\epsilon<1$) then the same $N$ works for every $\epsilon' \ge \epsilon$ so you are covering all the cases. For the log part, although it results in exactly same thing, I'd personally take $\log_{\lambda}$ on both sides and flip the inequality. Why inequality is flipped? It's not something to do with multiplying by negative sign, it is because $\log_{\lambda}$ is decreasing for $\lambda\in (0,1)$

Comment: i think i understand most of my concerns. lastly do i need N = max {1, blah} i just wasnt sure N was positive is it ok to just caviliary through a one in there?

Comment: I don't see the necessity, if $N$ happened to be negative then $n>N$ would just mean for all $n\ge 1$. But the reason why it might be needed is that you are considering $n\ge 1$.

Comment: I see thank you very much it is now clear as mud!